# How to set category for the posts being posted through TDO Mini Forms wp-plugin

Tags: wordpress

1. I have activated TDO Mini Forms plugin and using the shortcode in my template
   page-

   ```
   <?php tdomf_the_form(1); ?>
   ```
2. I want the posts which are being submitted through this form should
   be added to my category1.
3. I can't figure out how to do so even by referring many forms and
   readme.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TDO Mini Forms -> Form Options submenu you go to the Settings tab there's a dropdown menu called 'Default Category of new submissions' that allows you to select the category you want.

Comment: one more help.i don't know what i did.But,suddenly instead of my "post title", "date and time" is displayed and also preview in my frontend not working.Please help.Thanks a lot for your reply.Again in need and also thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm, hard to say @VijayaNarayanasamy - If you go into Form Creator your custom fields will accept 'Form Hacker Macros' like <b>%%TITLE%%</b> to format titles. If preview isn't working double check you haven't introduced JS errors somehow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your instant reply.I got it working.i created the new form and then,worked out for me.Again thanks a lot.